# Counterexample to $F(x) = \int_{a}^{x} f(t) dt \implies F' \in L^1(a,b)$

Tags: real-analysis

Given $F(x) = \int_a^x f$, $F$ is continuous on $[a,b]$, and $F$ is differentiable almost everwhere, is it necessarily true that $F' \in L^1(a,b)$?. I'm pretty sure this is false, but I am having trouble showing it. Does anyone have a quick counterexample? Thanks!

Comment: How is $\int_a^b f$ a function of $x$?

Comment: Oops, fixed haha.

Comment: This is a very uninformative title. The 'real-analysis' tag already indicates that it's a real analysis question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the integral is considered as an improper Riemann integral, then it is false.  Try
$F(x) = \frac{\cos(\pi/x)}{x}$.

EDIT: Oops, missed the "continuous on $[a,b]$".  Make that
$F(x) = x\cos(\pi/x)$ (on $[0,1]$), noting that 
$$\int_0^1 |F'(x)|\ dx \ge \sum_{n=1}^\infty 
\left|F\left(\frac1n\right) - F\left(\frac{1}{n+1}\right)\right| = 
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(\frac{1}{n} + \frac{1}{n+1}\right) = \infty$$

Comment: $F$ is not continuous on $[0,1]$. I think you meant this interval.

Comment: There's something I don't follow. We need that $F$ is a.e. an antiderivative of $f$. Thus $F^\prime = f$  a.e., but $F^\prime$ for your example "looks" nonintegrable on $[0,1]$, so  $\int f$ doesn't exist. What am I missing?

Comment: $f(x) = \cos(\pi/x) + (\pi/x) \sin(\pi/x)$ on $(0,1)$, and for any $\epsilon > 0$,
$\int_\epsilon^1 f(x)\ dx = F(1) - F(\epsilon)$.  Then as an improper Riemann integral, $\int_0^1 f(x)\ dx = \lim_{\epsilon \to 0+} (F(1) - F(\epsilon)) = F(1)$ exists.

Comment: In order for $g(x) = \int_0^x g^\prime (t) dt + g(0)$, it is necessary and sufficient that $g$ be absolutely continuous on $[0,1]$. On the other hand, every absolutely continuous function on $[a,b]$ is of bounded variation on $[a,b]$. But it is well known that $x\sin (1/x)$ is not of bounded variation on $[0,1]$, hence not absolutely continuous there, hence is not the integral of its derivative. In other words, $F(x) \not= \int F^\prime(x) dx$.

Comment: That should have been $x \cos(1/x)$ is not BV to match your $F$.

Comment: AsI said, it's not the Lebesgue integral, but it is an improper Riemann integral.